When to use symmetric vs asymmetric (periodic) window functions?
Libraries like scipy typically offer constructing window functions in a symmetric or asymmetric flavor. I'm aware of the rule of thumb:

Use symmetric for filter analysis.
Use asymmetric for spectral analyses like STFT.

I have never really seen a good explanation of this rule of thumb, and I would be interested where exactly this is coming from.
To thoroughly understand it, it may be interesting to address related questions:

What happens if one would do it the other way around?
Regarding STFT, does it actually depend on the window length? I.e., is the recommendation "use asymmetric" just a result of using almost exclusively even window lengths (for performance, FFT friendly), and would the recommendation flip when actually using an odd window length?


Here are a few examples of where I had seen this "rule of thumb" — perhaps an exaggeration after all:

In the docstrings in scipy for the individual window functions: When True (default), generates a symmetric window, for use in filter design. When False, generates a periodic window, for use in spectral analysis.
In Matlab's equivalent (see the sflag documentation): "symmetric" — Use this option when using windows for filter design. "periodic" — This option is useful for spectral analysis [...]
In torch's docstring: periodic flag determines whether the returned window trims off the last duplicate value from the symmetric window and is ready to be used as a periodic window with functions like torch.stft().


ah, I see what you mean – the sym: bool parameter on the window-generating functions, right? I think this is mainly so that if you use an algorithm that applies a symmetric window, but only needs half the window as input (because it can internally construct the other half to make it symmetric), can be directly executed. Never heard of your "rule of thumb", though! So, maybe you can find in which context that rule was given? It seems a bit overly broad as stated without context.

I agree with Marcus here: I have never heard that rule of thumb either, Can provide a reference with some context ? I have occasionally used half windows for fade ins/fade out or truncating impulse responses but that's about it.

@MarcusMüller Yes exactly, I've added some examples where I had seen it.

It’s very nitpicky, but I’m assuming it has to do with the following considerations:

The window method for filter design  consists in windowing an ideal infinite duration filter (such as a $\tt{sinc}$) to make it realizable. Most of the time, linear phase is a requirement, and that’s made possible with coefficients that reflect symmetry.

The DFT assumes periodicity. When doing spectral analysis, a periodic window “wraps” around, which means that the window function aligns the beginning and end points of the windowed segment, avoiding discontinuities when the signal is treated as periodic.



What happens if one would do it the other way around?

Try a few experiments! I don’t think you’ll see much difference in the spectral analysis case. For filter design, you would, depending on the characteristics of the impulse response (especially for very short filters).

@bluenote10 if this answer is satisfactory, please accept it so that others can benefit. Otherwise feel free to comment if you want more details ;)
